# Color outlier dots above a specific value in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

**How do I color outliers that are above a specific value using ggplot2 in R?**.

(Sorry for the seemingly easy question, I am a beginner. the reason why is that these are frequencies of a value of 0, I am then transforming this column of data by taking the -log10(). So anything that has a frequency of 0 would then be transformed into Inf. Attached is a screenshot of my plot, essentially I want to make all the outlier points above 10 on the y axis to be a different color.[image]

```
boxplots <- function(df){
    
    df$'frequency'[is.na(df$'frequency')] <- 0.00
    
    df$'-log10(frequency)' <- -log10(df$'frequency')
    
    x <- data.frame(group = 'x', value = df$'-log10(frequency)'[df$'Type'=='x'])
    y <- data.frame(group = 'y', value = df$'-log10(frequency)'[df$'Type'=='y'])
    z <- data.frame(group = 'z', value = df$'-log10(frequency)'[df$'Type'=='c=z'])
    
    plot.data <<- rbind(x, y, z)
    
    
    labels <- c("z", "y", "z")
    
   t<-plot.data %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = group, y = value, fill = group))+
        geom_boxplot()+
        scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha = 0.6)+
        geom_jitter(color="black", size=0.4, alpha=0.9) +
        theme_ipsum() +
        theme(
          legend.position="none",
          plot.title = element_text(size=11)
        ) +
        ggtitle("Distribution of -log10(frequency) by Type") +
        xlab("Type")+
        ylab("-log10(frequency)")+
        scale_x_discrete(labels=labels)+
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10), breaks = seq(0, 10, by = 2))
    
    print(t)


    s<<-t
    

    ggsave("frequency_by_type.png", plot = t) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just create a new column indicating wheather it is an outlier or not and map this to the geom_jitter color. I resumed the answer in a smaller example but you should be able to fit this accordingly:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

plot.data <- data.frame(group = c("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2"),
                        value = c(1,5,10,6,3,1,5,10,6,3))

t<-plot.data %>%
  mutate(outlier = ifelse(value >9, "YES", "NO")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = value, fill = group))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_jitter(aes(group, value, color = outlier) , size=2, alpha=0.9)+
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha = 0.6)

t
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
# Basic box plot
p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
p
# Rotate the box plot
p + coord_flip()
# Notched box plot
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + 
  geom_boxplot(notch=TRUE)
# Change outlier, color, shape and size
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour="red", outlier.shape=8,
                outlier.size=4)
```